# How can I text in between "dollar signs" on MSE.

Tags: support, mathjax

Suppose I have to write $\sum a_g$ such that $g \in G$ then can I start with "dollar sign" and then write whole thing and end "dollar sign" in last without italicising or any effect on my text "such that".
Like $this gets italicised$....

Answer (score 11):

Do you mean something like: $\{n\in\mathbb N; n\text{ is even}\}$?

Typeset as: `$\{n\in\mathbb N; n\text{ is even}\}$`

I will add that it is also mentioned here (warning - contains lot of MathJax, do not open from slow mobile devices): [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

---

In my personal opinion there is not much reason to use this in inline text. It makes sense when you want to define some set and want to have it as a single formula. Or when you use centered formulas
$$2\mathbb N = \{n\in\mathbb N; n\text{ is even}\}.$$

But I would write: "Consider all sums $\sum\limits_{n\in A} a_n$ where $A\subseteq 2\mathbb N$." (without using \text) rather than "Consider all sums $\sum\limits_{n\in A} a_n\text{ where }A\subseteq 2\mathbb N$." (which uses \text). (The first one was typeset as `Consider all sums $\sum\limits_{n\in A} a_n$ where $A\subseteq 2\mathbb N$.` The second one was typeset as `Consider all sums $\sum\limits_{n\in A} a_n\text{ where }A\subseteq 2\mathbb N$.`)

Although they might look similar, I think that distinguishing what is text and what is mathematical formula is useful.

Comment: yes... thank you..